# LaTeX, problem with bk1

Tags: eclipse, texlipse

I use some LaTeX style which includes `bk1\@ptsize.clo` by the line
`\input{bk1\@ptsize.clo}`.

However, my LaTeX environment (I'm using texlipse) produces error
"bk1\@ptsize.clo was not found". Despite of the error, it seems everything works
fine. How can I get rid of this annoying error message? If I remove the line
I get a 'serious' compilation error (I should also add I'm using pdfLaTeX).

Comment: This looks very odd. Can you post an example? `\@ptsize` should expand to `0`, `1` or `2`, so loading for example `bk10.cls`.

Comment: A wild guess, but this is probably a problem with eclipse not interpreting the LaTeX code and trying to load a non existing file.

Comment: Cls file that I'm using contains:
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
\input{bk1\@ptsize.clo}
Changing to
\input{bk10.clo} causes the error to dissapear.

Answer (score 1):

By `\newcommand\@ptsize{}` as comment #3 showed the cls file obviously defines `\@ptsize` to be empty. It should be set to a value like Joseph commented. This minimal example can be compiled and loads bk10.clo:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@ptsize{0}
\input{bk1\@ptsize.clo} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

I'm sure this works with TeXlipse as well.