# Problem with \@ptsize.clo using texlipse

Tags: fontsize, texlipse

I am currently writing my thesis. I have been provided with a class from my university for writing the thesis. I am facing problem with running the class. when I compile I get the "the included Latex file "size1\@ptsize.clo" was not found. While parsing through the class file I also found that there is a warning ("no argument following \newcommand") at the line

```
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
```

The complete code is given below

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{kfupm_thesis}
          [2007/03/18 v2.1
KFUPM MS/Ph.D. thesis/dissertation template.]
\usepackage{setspace}                   % package required to change spacing
\usepackage{ifthen}                     % for conditional programming
%\usepackage[compatible]{nomencl}

% new variables
\def\dept#1{\def\dept{#1}}
\def\program#1{\def\program{#1}}
\def\adviser#1{\def\adviser{#1}}
\def\memberone#1{\def\memberone{#1}}
\def\membertwo#1{\def\membertwo{#1}}
\def\memberthree#1{\def\memberthree{#1}}
\def\memberfour#1{\def\memberfour{#1}}
\def\chairman#1{\def\chairman{#1}}
\def\deanGS#1{\def\deanGS{#1}}
\def\DTC#1{\def\DTC{#1}}


%
% Warning and Error messages
%
\newcommand\paperwarning{%
\typeout{Only letter-sized paper allowed: Use`letterpaper' option instead}%
\@latex@warning{Incorrect paper size option set.}}

\newcommand\columnwarning{%
\typeout{Only one column output allowed.}%
\@latex@warning{Double-column not allowed.}}

% paper size preset to lattersize
% by SH
\setlength\paperheight {11in}%
\setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}

\newcommand\@ptsize{} %I get warning here
\newif\if@restonecol
\newif\if@titlepage
\@titlepagetrue
\newif\if@openright
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{a4paper}
    {\paperwarning}
\DeclareOption{a5paper}
   {\paperwarning}
\DeclareOption{b5paper}
   {\paperwarning}
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {11in}%
\setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{legalpaper}
   {\paperwarning}
\DeclareOption{executivepaper}
   {\paperwarning}
\DeclareOption{landscape}
   {\paperwarning}
\fi
\if@compatibility
  \renewcommand\@ptsize{0}
\else
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
\fi
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{oneside}{\@twosidefalse \@mparswitchfalse}
\fi
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\@twosidetrue  \@mparswitchtrue}
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}
\fi
\DeclareOption{titlepage}{\@titlepagetrue}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{notitlepage}{\@titlepagefalse}
\fi
\if@compatibility
\else
\DeclareOption{openright}{\@openrighttrue}
\DeclareOption{openany}{\@openrightfalse}
\fi
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{onecolumn}{\@twocolumnfalse}
\fi
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\@twocolumntrue}
\DeclareOption{leqno}{\input{leqno.clo}}
\DeclareOption{fleqn}{\input{fleqn.clo}}
\DeclareOption{openbib}{%
  \AtEndOfPackage{%
   \renewcommand\@openbib@code{%
      \advance\leftmargin\bibindent
      \itemindent -\bibindent
      \listparindent \itemindent
      \parsep \z@
      }%
   \renewcommand\newblock{\par}}%
}

\DeclareOption{ms}{%
    \program{MASTER OF SCIENCE}
    \DTC{Thesis Committee}
}
\DeclareOption{phd}{%
    \program{DOCTOR OF PHILOSOPHY}
    \DTC{Dissertation Committee}
}

\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,oneside,onecolumn,final,openany}
\ProcessOptions
\input{size1\@ptsize.clo} %I get error here
\setlength\lineskip{1\p@}
\setlength\normallineskip{1\p@}
```

I am using texlipse with texlive on Ubuntu 14.04. For compiling I am using latex+dvi2ps+ps2pdf.

I have tried this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3612/latex-problem-with-bk1?s=1%7C0.6072) but its not working for me

Comment: use an explicit size option such as `\documentclass[10pt]` then it should be OK. (The thesis class code could handle that better....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the class file could be better but as it is you have to give a size option, so use

```
\documentclass[10pt]{kfupm_thesis}
```

then it should be OK.

Comment: Actually, it was a problem with texlipse. As soon as I changed to texstudio, the code was working fine. I agree that the code could be better but since its compulsory to use the university provided class, I am stuck with it.

Comment: @Waqas the tex editor you use can not possibly affect the tex errors that you get. The code you posted will always generate an error if no size argument is given. Perhaps texstudio is using a different tex path with an updated version of the file.

Comment: Carlile yes I agree! Texlipse had some issues with the tex paths and was not recognizing a lot of packages in the texmf directory.